# Error: value <> is not a member of. Slick

Tags: scala, slick

i new in Scala. I going through tutorial and try to create something useful, but faced with strange error like this:

```
value <> is not a member of (slick.lifted.Rep[Long], slick.lifted.Rep[String], slick.lifted.Rep[String], slick.lifted.Rep[String])
```

[image]

My code:

```
package models

import java.sql.Timestamp

import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile._
import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api.stringColumnType
import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api.longColumnType
import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api.timestampColumnType
import slick.lifted.Tag


case class User(id: Long, name: String, email: String, PMAccount: String)
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "Users") {
  def id = column[Long]("id")
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def email = column[String]("email")
  def PMAccount = column[String]("PMAccount")

  def * = (id, name, email, PMAccount) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply(_))

}
```

Can anyone help me to understand this ?

Comment: If you find yourself in trouble I wrote an tutorial on how to setup Play framework with Slick for a MySQL database (should be similar to other databases): http://pedrorijo.com/blog/play-slick/ and code at github https://github.com/pedrorijo91/play-slick3-steps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have forgotten to import necessary api, just add this line to your code and it should work

```
import database.driver.api._

def * = (id, name, email, PMAccount) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply(_))
```